# How to config Maven compiler plugin to continue on a error occurrence and show them at the end of build process?

Tags: java, maven, javac

It's may be a simple question, but I've googled a lot and I didn't find something. I have a very big solution with more than 50 modules. I build solution using  Maven and the build process takes more than 10 minutes. When the Maven compiler plugin sees the first error, it halts. I want a way to tell the Maven compiler plugin to continue on error occurrence and at the last, show me all compile errors, to avoid the rebuilding the project after the fixing of first compile error

Comment: This is something IDEs are good for. Is that an option?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen The build process is more complicated than use IDEs to find compile errors. And There is a lot of code generation maven plugins during the build process

Comment: Does --fail-at-end work?

Comment: Some ides support the code generation if you follow maven conventions correctly. You might find that adapting your current build to those conventions will make it easier for all kinds of tools to help you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `mvn compiler:help -Ddetail=true` to see your Maven compiler options. This includes the option:

> failOnError
>
> Indicates whether the build will continue even if there are compilation errors.

You should be able to set this as a plugin property in your pom and make it optional via profiles, etc.

This will only apply to compilation errors - I would expect the build to halt on other Maven errors.